# jquery abstractly adding up values of parent div's data values

Tags: jquery, jquery-data

So I have several divs with the class "answers_total", and contained in it are five divs with a class "answer" and a data-answer attribute.

What I'm trying to do is somehow abstractly add up the total true values for each "answers_total" div and store them in a variable.  So for the first one here there are three "true" and in the second only two "true".  I'd need to be able to access each individual total, probably each have their own variable?  I'm not 100 percent sure.

I think you'd do this with $(".answers_total").each...

but I'm not sure where to go after that.  Any ideas on how to do something like this?  Maybe it's not possible or there is a better way to set up and do this?

Thanks so much for any help

```
<div class="answers_total">
    <div data-answer="true" class="answer">SPEECH</div>
    <div data-answer="false" class="answer">RELIGION AND BELIEF</div>
    <div data-answer="true" class="answer">PRESS</div>
    <div data-answer="true" class="answer">ASSEMBLY</div>
    <div data-answer="false" class="answer">PETITION</div>
</div>
<div class="answers_total">
    <div data-answer="false" class="answer">SPEECH</div>
    <div data-answer="true" class="answer">RELIGION AND BELIEF</div>
    <div data-answer="false" class="answer">PRESS</div>
    <div data-answer="true" class="answer">ASSEMBLY</div>
    <div data-answer="false" class="answer">PETITION</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function to which returns an array.. then use the `.length` property to find out how many of those `data-answer=true` exists in each `div.answers_total`

```
var x = $('.answers_total').map(function(i,v){
    return $('div[data-answer=true]',v).length; // return how many have data-answer=true
});
```

so

```
x[0] = 3 // which is the relevant to the first .answers_total div
x[1] = 2 // which is the relevant to the second .answers_total div
```

<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kJmjF/)</kbd>

If you wanted count of both true and false count you can do

```
var x = $('.answers_total').map(function (i, v) {
    return {
        true: $('div[data-answer=true]', v).length,
        false: $('div[data-answer=false]', v).length
    };
});
```

then

```
x[0].true = 3 // number of true in first div
x[0].false = 2 // number of false in first div
x[1].true = 2 // number of true in second div
x[1].false= 3 // number of false in second div
```

<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c9f2x/)</kbd>

Comment: hey thanks for taking the time to write that out and explain it, that's super helpful and I appreciate it!

Comment: @loriensleafs np :)  If you have any questions about how it works feel free to ask

Comment: thanks man.  Can I point you to this question I asked based on your answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260024/jquery-writing-one-click-statement-for-query-map-set-up-instead-of-3  You're very good at explaining the process in a short but clear way!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're looking to do with it after you're done, or what you mean by "abstract", but this should work:

```
var answerTotals = [];

$('.answers_total').each(function() {
    var results = { correct: 0, incorrect: 0 };
    $(this).find('.answer').each(function() {
        if ($(this).data('answer') == 'true')
            results.correct++;
        else
            results.incorrect++;
    });
    answerTotals.push(results);
});
```

Comment: basically I'm trying to determine if the person clicks the true values or not, so they click one true value, it gets counted, they click another....and when they click all of the true values a function happens...

Comment: how do you get at the individual values in this?

Comment: So you need to handle the click events, and every time one is clicked, iterate all of the answers and see if they are all correct. If so, do something, otherwise, do something else.

Comment: thanks for explaining that to me, sometimes it's hard to know how to put the pieces together and it can be helpful to have someone point you in the right direction.