# jquery writing one click statement for query.map set up instead of 3

Tags: jquery

I have several divs set up like so:

```
<div class="answers_total">
    <div data-answer="true" class="answer">SPEECH</div>
    <div data-answer="false" class="answer">RELIGION AND BELIEF</div>
    <div data-answer="true" class="answer">PRESS</div>
    <div data-answer="true" class="answer">ASSEMBLY</div>
    <div data-answer="false" class="answer">PETITION</div>
</div>
<div class="answers_total">
    <div data-answer="false" class="answer">SPEECH</div>
    <div data-answer="true" class="answer">RELIGION AND BELIEF</div>
    <div data-answer="false" class="answer">PRESS</div>
    <div data-answer="true" class="answer">ASSEMBLY</div>
    <div data-answer="false" class="answer">PETITION</div>
</div>
```

I'm adding up the true answers with jQuery.map() like so:

```
var x = $('.answers_total').map(function(i,v){
    return $('div[data-answer=true]',v).length; // return how many have data-answer=true
});
```

What I'm trying to do is write a super concise function for the click.  If I were to write it out for each one I'd do:

```
var x = $(".answers_total").map(function(i,v) {
    return $('div[data-answer=true]',v).length;
});

clicks = 0;

$(".answer").click(function() {
    jthis = this;

    if ( $(jthis).att("data-attribute") == "true" ) {
        clicks++;
        if ( clicks == x[0] ) {
            alert('you found all the true answers');   
        }
    }
});
```

The problem with writing it like this is I'd have to make a version of it for each "answers_total".  How would you change this so you only had to write it once?

Thanks for any help I can get on this.

Comment: use an each to give each one it's own scope, then define x and clicks inside of each of those private scopes. Also, don't forget `var`...

Comment: that's what I'm not 100 percent how to do, how to define x in an abstract way instead of x[2]

Comment: Ok - so the whole goal of this is if all `data-answer=true` elements inside a certain div is clicked.. do something?

Answer (score 0):

this solution uses the data- html 5 attributes correctly.  jQuery will wrap the html 5 functionality if hte browser client can't support it, otherwise it will allow the client to handle the "data-" processing inherently. (faster)

```
var $answers = $(".answers_total");
//put the true answer count in a data block associated to the .answers_total element, + a click count
$answers.each(function(index,elem){
  $(this).data("trueCount", $('div[data-answer=true]',this).length);
  $(this).data("clicks",0);
});

$(".answer").click(function(event){
//if someone clicks, and the answer is true, process the click and store it in the parent .answers_total
  if($(this).data("answer") == true){
   var clicks = $(this).closest(".answers_total").data("clicks" ) +1;
    $(this).closest(".answer_total").data("clicks",clicks);
//check if all the true answers are found
    if(clicks >= $(this).closest(".answers_total").data("trueCount")){
      alert("you've found all the true answers!");
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming you want to do something when all `data-answer=true` have been clicked inside the div - You really don't need the array of true answers then as you can do a check on each click

```
$('.answer').click(function(){
    var $el = $(this);
    if($el.data('answer')){ // if data-answer=true
        $el.attr('data-clicked','true'); // add data-clicked attribute to the data-true answer
        var totalClicked = $el.siblings('[data-clicked=true]').addBack().length; // total true elements clicked
        var totalTrueAnswer = $el.siblings('[data-answer=true]').addBack().length; // total available true elements
        if(totalClicked == totalTrueAnswer){ // if they equal
            alert('all found');
        }
    }
});
```

<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L8jCp/)</kbd>

Comment: is there a reason you put a $ in front of the el variable?

Comment: just so I know that it's a jQuery object :)

Comment: so are you only doing stuff for the data-answers=true? or are you doing something for both true and false?

Comment: only for when they're true

Comment: so addback just keeps track of the previous clicks?

Comment: so if you look at this `$el.siblings('[data-answer=true]').addBack()`.. i started at the current clicked element - I traversed to the siblings so now the collection only contains the siblings - I want to include the element I started out with(`$el`) so `.addBack()` adds back the previous selected element.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35542/discussion-between-loriensleafs-and-)